# PHP is_dir and mkdir not working on mapped network drive

Tags: php, windows, share, mkdir

I have mapped my Z: drive to point to a file share on another server on my network in Windows Explorer.  I can access the files and read/write just fine there.

When I try to execute mkdir() from PHP, I get a "No such file or directory" error.

As a test, I gave Everyone access to read, write, and execute and it is still not working.

The code I am using:

```
mkdir('Y:/newfolder/', 0777);
```

I have also tried mapping the drive again within PHP to no avail:

```
system('net use Y: "\\DEV01\share" Password1 /user:Administrator /persistent:no>nul 2>&1");
mkdir('Y:/newfolder/', 0777);
```

Please assist.

Comment: Can you submit the code you use to mkdir? Do you use the 2nd argument $mode

Comment: I have edited my original post to include the code examples.

Comment: try using \\ instead of / for the path

Comment: didn't fix the problem.  Both machines are part of a Workgroup btw.

Comment: mkdir('Y:\\newfolder'); is that what you tried?

Comment: yes I tried that as well as mkdir('Y:\\newfolder\\');

Comment: Have you tried `\\DEV01\share\newfolder`?

Comment: you might need to do \\\\DEV01\\share\\newfolder

Comment: none of those above worked either.

Comment: So its still the same error? Not a permission denied by any chance?

Comment: Might be - but I'm not getting a permission denied error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for your advice everyone.  It turned out to be a syntax error.  In the mapping code.  You must map the drive manually within the PHP script like I did above, except you have to escape your backslashes in there.  Instead of
`\\DEV01\share`, you must use `\\\\DEV01\\share`.